# AJAX callback not working, but data is being sent

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```js
$(".addToCart").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: baseURL + "/shop/addToCart",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      item_id: $(this).attr('data-id')
    },
    success: function(result) {
      alert('added');
      location.reload();
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: If the AJAX callback isn't triggered then it means your AJAX request returned an error response. Look at the network tab of devtools to figure out what the error is and debug it

Comment: Or add an [`error: function (jqXhr, statusText, statusCode) { ... }`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback.